# Usage of "the" in a gift note - please help

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I want to write a note to a gift for parents of my wife (and grandparents of our daughter). As it is a special occasion, I want it to be correct, but I am confused how to use "the".

The note will be:

"For (THE) parents and grandparents of (THE) wonderful girls".

Should it be with "the" or without it?

Comment: I'd say "to the parents and grandparents of two wonderful girls/children".  Still it sounds ambiguous.

Comment: @Centaurus - Could be *”for **my** two wonderful girls”*

Comment: @Jim Good call.

Answer (score 0):

The first "the" is necessary--imagine the group receiving the gift (these particular parents and grandparents) are part of a larger group (ALL the kids' parents and grandparents). It makes it sound more specific, like YOU receiving the gift are THE relatives in question.

The second "the" is negotiable. I wouldn't use it--"here is a present for the relatives of wonderful girls" sounds more intimate than "the wonderful girls" -- what did you just meet them? Now, if they are eventful in your life [if you could finish the phrase "the wonderful girls who gave me a ride"] the might make some sense.

I want to write a note to a gift for parents of my wife (and grandparents of our daughter). As it is a special occasion, I want it to be correct, but I am confused how to use "the".

I would put"

"For the parents and grandparents of wonderful girls".